# Git signing commit issue

Tags: git, gnupg

I have setup a gpg key :
`gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/anonymous/.gnupg'`
`/home/anonymous/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`
`---------------------------------`
`pub   rsa4096/BA4FF7362A7BD6EF 2018-11-24 [SC]`
`40CF42C51EFF9574102F3060BA4FF7362A7BD6EF`
`uid                 [ultimate] **** (first key) <****@example.com>`
`sub   rsa4096/05ED809ACFF9175E 2018-11-24 [E]`

And I have configured git global like such
`git config --global user.signingkey BA4FF7362A7BD6EF`

But when I try to commit :
`git commit -a -S -m 'git commit'`

I get the following error:
`error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object`

Comment: Do you have the rights to write in the folder? Could be also because is a hidden folder?

Comment: Have you configure which gpg program to use ?

Comment: `GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -a -S -m 'git commit'` Run with `GIT_TRACE` to get a more detailed log of what's happening.  It can give you an idea of what's going wrong. Share the log if you are not able to figure it out.

Comment: @vishnu After running the command : GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -a -S -m 'git commit' the output was : 05:56:12.959594 git.c:328               trace: built-in: git 'commit' '-a' '-S' '-m' 'git commit'
05:56:12.960518 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'gpg' '--status-fd=2' '-bsau' 'B3AB7B429CF88DA7'
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

Comment: I'm getting the same error, and I wonder if this is a bug with the new version of gpg. What version of gpg and gpg-agent are you using? What happens when you try `echo "test" | gpg --verbose --clearsign`

Comment: `echo "test" | gpg --verbose --clearsign` reponds with `gpg: no running gpg-agent - starting '/usr/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg: waiting for the agent to come up ... (5s)
gpg: waiting for the agent to come up ... (4s)
gpg: waiting for the agent to come up ... (3s)
...
gpg: waiting for the agent to come up ... (0s)
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
gpg: keydb_search failed: No agent running
gpg: no default secret key: No agent running
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No agent running
`